# How to throw more than 1 possible exception for a single statement in python

Tags: python, oracle

I have  this statement:

```
try:
   cx_oracle..connect(username/password@hostname:port/service)
except cx_Oracle.DatabaseError:
   #do_stuff
```

Let's say I provide a valid `username`, an empty `password`, an invalid  `hostname` and an invalid `service` name; and I am writing conditions inside `except` block so that based on Oracle error code something will be done.

How can I list out all possible database errors without correcting the first error that has occurred?

```
Actual o/p: TNS: listener does not currently know of service requested 
Required o/p:  TNS: listener does not currently know of service requested
               empty password
               Invalid host
```

Answer (score 2):

You can put multiple errors in a tuple. Then you can access whichever error with e.

```
try:
    cx_oracle..connect(username/password@hostname:port/service)
except (cx_Oracle.DatabaseError, Error1, Error2) as e:
    # do stuff
```

You can also have multiple excepts.

```
try:
    cx_oracle..connect(username/password@hostname:port/service)
except cx_Oracle.DatabaseError:
    # do stuff
except Error1:
    # do stuff
```

Comment: I have a possibility of more than 1 database error and the code shows only the first occured error

Comment: I do not know the names of your errors, but basically you can replace the "Error1" and "Error2" with which ever errors you want to catch, including different database errors

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem not too long ago, found this somewhere on stackoverflow, it catches multiple errors:

```
    try:
        cur.execute("insert into project_source_code(project, path) values(:project_id,:prj_path)",(project_id, prj_path))

    except cx_Oracle.DatabaseError as e:
        error, = e.args
        print(error.code)
        print(error.message)
        print(error.context)
```